# erroneously closed question

Tags: support, duplicates, vote-to-reopen

["Infinite" page or finite pages, depending on how viewed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695263/infinite-page-or-finite-pages-depending-on-how-viewed)

This was closed as a duplicate.

This is NOT a duplicate of the question to which it was redirected, since it contains an additional question not at all included in that question nor addressed by the answers.

Is there a thread on meta to which one posts requests for reopening?

Could the person who redirected it read more carefully?

Comment: I have now set in bold the part of the question that was disregarded by the person who erroneously closed this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

I've voted to re-open the question.

I think the question can benefit from the following:

- *A minimal example* that creates a simple document that spans a number of pages. This will make it clear what document class and setup you're using to produce your output. This way answerers don't have to reinvent the wheel, however small a wheel it may be.
- A *visual* of what the different output should look like between the PDF and its non-paginated counterpart. This will make it clear to the answerers what you expect as an output. This would circumvent questions like

  - Should the unpaginated output also be PDF, or HTML?
  - How do you want to indicate the page break on the unpaginated output?
- Clarity on what you mean by "depending on how [the document] is viewed." The ultimate output will be electronic, so the assumption is that there will be two different electronic versions, yet you mention a physical print-out and an electronic PDF view.